# Filter query nested within the main solr query

Tags: solr

Solr provides a filter query (parameter `fq`) feature which allows terms to be matched in a binary manner without affecting the document's score. In addition the set of documents matching a filter query is cached for reuse with varying main queries (parameter `q`).

In a particular application, I would like to match documents without affecting the score (I am less concerned about caching at present), but am only able to modify the main `q` parameter.

I would like the output to be equivalent to:

```
/select?q=foo&fq=bar
```

I had thought I could use [LocalParams](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LocalParams) do something like:

```
/select?q=%2bfoo %2b_query_:"{!fq=bar} *:*"
```

(Note: `%2b` parses to a `+`, making those terms prefixed by it mandatory.) I would expect the LocalParams term to act like `/select?q=*:*&fq=bar`, but `fq=bar` seems to have no effect. Why is it not supported?

Would it instead be reasonable to implement a new query parser called `filter` such that the following were instead possible?

```
/select?q=%2bfoo %2b_query_:"{!filter} bar"
```

The LocalParams term here would be interpreted as running `/select?q=bar` but rectifying its score to 0 or 1.

Or is there some standard function that allows me to modify the score assigned to a term so it gets rectified to 0 or 1?